Архаичный синоним к слову "серьёзный"
Я стал думать недавно о том, как, может быть, говорили "серьёзный" на древней Руси, или по минимуму до прихода этого слова в русский язык. Оно явно заимствовано, можно сравнить с английским serious и французским sérieux.
Есть примеры в других славянских языках: в сербском "серьёзный" будет "озбиљан" (от "збити се", родственно русскому "сбыться"). Существуют ли аналоги этому слову в русском?
Конкретнее, было ли когда-то какое-то другое слово, может со славянским корнем, которое потом заменило слово "серьёзный"?

Тут и в русском-то сложно подобрать синоним понятию нешутливый (серьезный), не то что в славянском. Наверное неправильно думать, что в языках полным полно слов на все случаи жизни. Кучи слов тупо нет. Взять например актуальное понятие - "рыба или мясо" как пища. Ну нет такого слова в русском. Или другие примеры можно приводить

Я конечно понимаю, что есть слова, которые нельзя сказать никак иначе, и не говорю, что это плохо. Просто вдруг стал интересоваться. А так как у меня сербский - родной язык, мне просто природнее всего с ним сравнивать.
Я выбрал слово "серьёзный", так как считаю его довольно-таки основным понятием, как рыба или мясо. У русских наверное не всегда был контакт с латыней и прочими языками, и я посчитал, что до заимствования "серьёзный" наверное было что-то другое.

А, так у вас второй язык в загашнике, то-то я удивляюсь разумности вопроса. Согласен, что "серьезный" в смысле "нешутливый" это актуальное понятие оно как-будто должно присутствовать в любом языке. Но не  удивлюсь, если есть множество актуальных понятий, неоформленных в языках в виде отдельных слов. Рыба оформлена, мясо тоже, а вот рыба или мясо (пища) никак не оформлена. Наверняка в сербском есть для "рыбы или мяса" как пищи отдельное слово, или тоже нет? "нешутливый"/"не склонный шутить" - так не говорят в русском, нужен какой-то позитивный синоним, но что-то нет его.

Может, слово суровый подойдет?
В этимологическом словаре Фасмера:
суро́вый — диал. сурово́й, вост.-русск. (Даль), укр. суро́вий "небеленый", блр. суро́вы "суровый", др.-русск. суровъ "сырой, дикий", ст.-слав. соуровъ ὠμός (Супр.), болг. су́ров "сырой, жесткий, свежий, сочный", чеш., слвц. surový "суровый, жестокий", польск. surowy "суровый", в.-луж., н.-луж. surowy "сырой, невареный; суровый, строгий".
В толковом словаре Ожегова:
суровый
4. Очень строгий, серьёзный. Суровый приговор. Подвергнуть суровой критике.
— Глупости говорите… — вмешался суровый Филипп Филиппович, но Борменталь его перебил: — Не беспокойтесь, Филипп Филиппович, я сам (М. Булгаков. Собачье сердце).
В словаре русского языка X–XVIII веков (Е. Отин; стр. 347):

СУРОВЫЙ. Жестокий. // Рязанцы же сурови суще (будучи. — Е. О.) друг к другу рекоша: «Не емлете (не имейте. — Е. О.) со собою доспеха (боевого снаряжения. — Е. О.), ни щита, ни копия, ни иного оружия, но токмо (только. — Е. О.) емлете с собою едины (одни. — Е. О.) ужища (верёвки. — Е. О.) (Рогожский летописец, 1321 г.).


Очень интересно, спасибо Вам за ответ!


Слово серьезный известно в русском языке с середины 18 века, у Фонвизина в форме сурьезный в "Бригадире", 1769 год.

Заимствовано из французского, где serieuse восходит к позднелатинскому seriosus от serus — «поздний, зрелый, длительный».

Но в современном языке у него 5 значений, которые имеют свои синонимические ряды, так что к каждому значению надо искать синонимы.

Да только  чтобы были в языке слова, должны быть понятия, а вот это вопрос.  Думается, что были не все. Задумчивость, сосредоточенность, истинность, глубина — вряд ли все это явно существовало и было обозначено словами.


Или многие качества были осознаны именно в 18 веке, когда появилось слово серьезный?  Пока они не обозначены словами, то и не получают в обществе развития. Так что здесь тесная связь.

Существенный, значимый, важный близки к слову великий.

Интересно слово суровый, оно восходит к значению грубый, сырой, неотделанный. И если жестокий, то потому что не имеющий должного воспитания и образования? Или это положительная оценка, а какая?  Требовательность?


ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Из словаря Черных, суровый
В др.-рус языке известно с 11 века: жилами суровыми (СЫРЫМИ) бити. Далее — ДИКИЙ, ЖЕСТОКИЙ.  Далее: угрюмо-сумрачный, твердый, непреклонный.
Уже в текстах XI века прилагательное суровый, в отличие от прилагательного сырой, употреблялось в значении "дикий, жестокий": "Въсехъ странъ суровейшем предамъ вы Вавилоняномъ"; "Якоже въ вълъцехъ соуровыихъ агнице бесквьрньные" (1096 г.). Это значение не теряет актуальности и в более поздних древнерусских текстах: "Соуровый бо и сверепый и оубийственный образъ" (XIII в.); "Иродъ суровый".
А дальше? До серьезного так и не дошли: в современном словаре такого значения (суровый)  нет.  А угрюмая сумрачность стала считаться вдумчивостью, строгостью и глубиной мыслей.  Где-то мы сейчас)
Поэтому вопрос представляется мне очень неопределенным, и вряд ли в качестве ответа можно подобрать одно слово.
Мы не серьезные, мы — суровые? (см. выше). Но не хочется думать, что это так.
СУРОВЫЙ
https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/серьёзный
 СЕРЬЁЗНЫЙ, [франц. serieux (serieuse)]. 1. Отличающийся 
 вдумчивостью и требовательностью к себе, к работе, к 
 окружающим; глубокий, не легкомысленный. 2. 
 Сосредоточенный, занятый какими-л. мыслями, заботами; 
 задумчивый, невесёлый. 3. Проникнутый ответственностью, 
 основательностью, взвешенностью; требующий такого 
 отношения. С. подход к делу.  4. Большой и важный, 
 существенный; фундаментальный.5. Отличающийся глубиной; 
 нелегковесный; истинный, подлинный. 


Да, я согласен с Вами, что вопрос был несколько неопределен. Наверное в поисках самих синонимов в современном толковом словаре и кроется ответ, но мне было очень интересно узнать про такие примеры, как "суровый" и "жестокий". Спасибо Вам за ответ!

Слово само по себе любопытное и даже противоречивое в чем-то.  И надо смотреть, с каким значением оно входит в язык.  Вот Грибоедов: А дядя! что твой князь? что граф?
Сурьезный взгляд, надменный нрав.  Но оно появилось на сто лет раньше. Вероятно, значимый, важный.  Строгий в мыслях? Твердый? Но  слово строгий тоже позднее. Сама бы послушала мнение знающих людей на эту тему –  здесь нужно общее языкознание хорошо знать. Или чувствовать, что ли)
